# Is there a HitTest property or something in VCL for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, mouseevent, firemonkey, vcl, hittest

In FireMonkey (FMX), every `TControl` component has a [`HitTest`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.HitTest) property that allows me to enable or disable mouse events on the component.

Is there something like this in VCL? I tried searching and looking for it, but I can't find a `HitTest` property anywhere.

If there isn't `HitTest` for VCL, how can the same be achieved? Can someone provide a code example on how to do it in VCL perhaps?

I am using Embarcadero Delphi 12.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such property in VCL.

All FMX controls are entirely custom made with very little management by the OS, so mouse handling is managed by FMX itself, thus exposing a `HitTest` property is trivial for FMX to do.

But in VCL, only `TGraphicControl` descendants are implemented like that. `TWinControl` descendants, on the other hand, are wrappers for Win32 `HWND` windows and so mouse handling is largely managed by the OS instead.

For windowed VCL controls, you will have to manually subclass each control as needed to handle the Win32 [`WM_NCHITTEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest) message directly. The VCL doesn't normally handle that message (except in a few select cases).

For example:

```pascal
private
  PrevWndProc: TWndMethod;
  procedure MyWndProc(var Message: TMessage);

procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PrevWndProc := SomeControl.WindowProc;
  SomeControl.WindowProc := MyWndProc;
end;

procedure TMyForm.MyWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  PrevWndProc(Message);
  if Message.Msg = WM_NCHITTEST then
  begin
    ...
    if MessageShouldBeIgnored then
      Message.Result := HTNOWHERE;
  end;
end;
```

For a graphic control, you would have to subclass its windowed `Parent` control instead.

However, be careful with how you modify the default behavior of `WM_NCHITTEST`:

[WM_NCHITTEST is for hit-testing, and hit-testing can happen for reasons other than the mouse being over your window](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110218-00/?p=11453)

Comment: "TWinControl descendants, on the other hand, are wrappers for Win32 controls [...]" Not necessarily. TCustomControl descendants are typically fully implemented in VCL code.

Comment: (But of course, this depends on how you define "Win32 control".)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand `TCustomControl` is still a windowed control. Even if its UI is custom-drawn, it is still a Win32 window object, so it gets a lot of default behavior (like mouse handling) from the OS.

Comment: Of course, but is my completely custom-made text edit control a "wrapper[...] for [a] Win32 control [...]"? Of course we both agree about how things are, but formulating this in English in a way that cannot be misunderstood is not always trivial. (Didn't downvote.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand ok, I reworded it

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hey Remy. Most of what you're typing here is a bit of Greek to me. Is there any chance you can add a code example please?

Comment: @MartinKakhuis I added an example

Comment: @Remy Isn't `procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;` a lot easier? Or is there a reason you're doing it that way?

Comment: @JerryDodge if you are writing your own component class, then yes `message` is easier/cleaner (though, I do sometimes like to override `WndProc()` instead to hide which messages my components depend on). But, that is not what my example above is doing. Its subclassing an existing object, for instance a standard component that is dropped on the Form at design-time.

Comment: @Remy Ah, I see.